# Android sometimes my secondary storage.exists() returns true even if I unmount it

Tags: android, android-intent, storage, android-sdcard

I tried to detect secondary external storage(**SD card**) unmounted using broadcast receiver, and if so start running a thread and finish it until SD card is mounted. It works fine occasionally. however, when I try to know if directory exists or not, it sometimes **returns true even if SD card is unmounted**! Why does it happen? Is it because of the cache memory or something else? I really have no idea how I should solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that it's emulating the SD Card via the internal storage. Can you verify the contents of the external storage after unmounting SD card? (Also are you physically removing the SD card?)

Comment: Thanks for reply. For the first question, I don't think I could do that because I have a tab with a list of videos on sdcard, and it shows nothing when removing sdcard. Secondly, yes I do remove SD card physically to take care of bad-removal only. Is it probably because of physical removing?

Comment: @Junsfavorite that sounds like it's caching then. A lot of phones will cache thumbnails/etc from SD Card on boot.